# vim netrw opens long file names incorrectly with timestamp

Tags: vim, netrw

When I try and open a file with a long name in netrw in a directory listing with file date showing it will open the file as `testfile999 Sun 20 Feb.....` including the date hence resulting in a new file buffer not the file.

To reproduce:

1. open netrw
2. press i to show directory listing with file dates.
3. open a file with a long name so that the filename runs into the next column
4. netrw doesn't open the file and instead opens a new file buffer with the wrong filename.

Is there a setting to fix that.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Found a bug in $FOSS_PROGRAM? Use [its issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my .vimrc and it solved the issue:

```
let g:netrw_dynamic_maxfilenamelen = 32
```

Unfortunately, this also introduces a very specific issue when using liststyle=1 where some directories are shown as empty files. For now I can live with that.